# Помогите с БД (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создал в моей БД в pgadmin 2 таблицы stud и projects теперь мне нужно создать еще таблицу StudWithProj и туда засунуть номер студента (n) группу (gr) и распределить для студентов  проекты из таблицы projects. Как можно не вручную это сделать ?

Через SELECT INTO ?

Comment: и зачем туда пихать gr если она уже есть у студента?

Comment: @teran куда пихать ? Я делал составной ПК **n** и **gr**?

Comment: для таблицы связи студент-проект нужен составной пк из id студент и id-проекта. Студент вроде и так однозначно должен попадать в какую то группу и эта информация хранится в таблице студентов. В таблице свзяи с проектами она избыточна

Comment: @teran а если у меня в таблице students n студента это номер по журналу т.е он повторяется

Comment: и как миграцию в следующем учебном году будете проводить? заменить номер группы? А если студента отчислят, то номера будут сдвигаться? Если нужен номер  в журнале, то сделайте отдельный столбец и там и храните. а в качестве ключа инкремент.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE StudWithProj AS
SELECT s.n AS n_id, s.gr AS gr_id, p.n_t AS project_id, p.name_t
FROM stud s 
CROSS JOIN Projects p;
```

Comment: Это где ж у автора написано, что каждый студент участвует в каждом из имеющихся проектов?